# Import custom dashboard template to grafana and update prometheus scape config using istioctl

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, istio

I'm using **istioctl 1.6.8** and with the help of command `istioctl install --set profile=demo --file istio-config.yaml` I was able to deloy istio to my cluster with grafana and prometheus enabled. My **istio-config.yaml file** looks like this.

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          serviceAnnotations:
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
  values:
    grafana:
      security:
        enabled: true
```

I have some **grafana dashboard json** files which I need to **export to the newly installed grafana** and for these dashboards to work I have to **add some exporter details in to my prometheus scrape-config**.

My question:

Apart from importing dashboard via grafana UI, **is there any way I could do this by passing relevant details to my istio-config.yaml**? If not, can anyone suggest any other approach?

(One approach that I have in my mind is to overwrite the existing resources with custom yaml using kubectl apply -f -)

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I don't have a working example, but you can try to set it up via IstioOperator. See the values file for reference of the parameters to set: https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/1.6.8/manifests/addons/values-grafana.yaml#L32

Comment: @ChristophRaab I tried this approach but it failed saying attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: I added an answer, some time has passed since my comment and some things changed with new istio versoin gerading grafana.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't investigate on this any further. With Istio 1.7 Prometheues/Kiali/Grafana installation with istioctl was deprecated and will be removed with Istio 1.8.

See: https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/addon-rework/

In the further you will have to set up your own prometheus/grafana eg with helm so I would recommand to work in this direction.